# Wire going between O terminal and B terminal

Tags: thermostat

I'm trying to figure out if the Nest Thermostat is compatible with our system using their online checker where you have to select what wires you have. I see that we have one orange wire that looks like it is going between the O terminal and the B terminal. Does this mean I should enter the wires as O/B or O separate AND B separate?
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "going between the O and B" - I only see one orange wire.

Comment: I also don't see such a jumper. Please revise to clarify.

Comment: Wait, are the orange and blue wires butt-spliced? That seems silly when one of them alone would've reached.

Comment: To clarify, I am not saying they are connected or that there is a jumper. The single orange wire seems to be going not to the O terminal or the B terminal, but between them.

Comment: Seems like it might just be perception making it appear that the O wire is "in between" the two terminals.  Look at it from straight-on (eyes same height as the thermostat plate) and you should see that the wire goes into a hole "under" the spring terminal.  They might appear a little bent, but that's most likely just a function of looking at it from slightly above.

Comment: ...also, points to the installer who failed to install the thing level, even with the bubble built into the plate. :)

Comment: Chris O- I see what you mean. Yes, the orange wire IS going into only the O terminal. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post photos of how the air handler is wired?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, we can't see very well what you mean that **O** and **B** are connected somehow. Typically if they were connected, this would be done with a jumper (and usually between **Rh** and **Rc**, in my non-professional experience). I've mostly seen that on screw terminals, not your push-in terminals though.

If you're sure they're connected (like there's a splice that splits the wire and one's connected to **O** and one to **B**, but they travel together down one wire to the HVAC unit) that should be **O/B**.

Nest's setup process will have some selections where you can diagnose and choose what equipment is connected to that terminal. Someone very familiar with HVAC can probably tell you what that would be, I only know Nest because I've moved a lot and installed them each time (and I keep leaving them behind like an idiot when I sell the house).

Note that when you go to [Nest's Compatibility Checker](https://nest.com/widget/thermostat-compatibility/), if you enter this wire as **O/B**, or **O**, or **B**, it's compatible. If you enter it as **O** *AND* **B** it says it's not. But if it's the same wire in the cable going to HVAC, it's **O/B** and your old thermostat has it tasked to both. Nest retasks these lines through software and relays.

Comment: For a little more context... heat pump systems change from heat to cool in different ways.  Some are normally heat unless power is applied to O, some are normally cool unless power is applied to B (those could be reversed) and some need power applied to O or B to change back and forth.  There's not a reason that O and B would be connected to each other, so I think we are missing some details.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to figure out- how to enter these wires into the compatibility check on the Nest website. I did not say that they are connected, nor that there is a jumper. What I see is one single orange wire that is not connected to the O terminal (it's below that), or the B terminal (it's above that), but looks like it is between them. So would I enter this on the compatibility check as "O/B" or "O" AND "B"? Because that difference will tell me if my device is compatible (O/B) or not (O AND B).